# React-Bootstrap Rows/Columns are not the full width of the screen (Only 50% of it)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My experience with CSS and Bootstrap, when it comes to positioning and resizing elements on the screen, has been bloody awful ever since I started writing HTML. All I am trying to do (in my React project) is position 2 elements on the screen side by side, the element on the left needs to be 80% of the screens width and the element on the right has to be 20% of the screens width. Obviously for bootstrap to be able to do this, it requires 4 weeks writing code, 20+ stack overflow questions and 1 human sacrifice.

Below is the main app component with a `<React.Fragment/>` tag and a `<Container/>` with `<Row/>` and `<Col/>` inside that:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>Hello</Col>
            <Col>Hello2</Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MainContent;
```

Expected result? `Hello` will be on the left of screen and `Hello2` will be on the right of screen smack bang in the middle. Just as the docs suggest [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/).

But of course that doesn't happen. The row is centered in the middle of the screen and is about half of the screen size in total width.

To illustrate:
`25% Whitespace | Hello1 | Hello2 | 25% Whitespace`

Honestly, I have no idea what to do. Setting the margins to 0 will put it on the left of screen but it is still not the full width.

Someone please help me, I've had enough :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default in `bootstrap`, `container` `width` and `max-width` is set to some `px` like,

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    max-width: 720px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.container {
    max-width: 540px;
} 

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

You have to set `max-width:  100%` like,

```
.container {
  max-width: '100%'  //This will make container to take screen width
}
```

Or, Another way is, you can add `fluid` prop to `Container`,

> **fluid** - Allow the Container to fill all of it's availble horizontal space.

```
<Container fluid>
  ...
</Container>
```

**Note:** Here `Col` will take by default `equal space`.

> The Col lets you specify column widths across 5 breakpoint sizes (xs, sm, md, large, and xl).

For example,

```
<Row>
    <Col xs={6} md={8}>
      xs=6 (6 parts of screen on small screen) md=8 (8 parts of screen on medium screen)
    </Col>
    <Col xs={6} md={4}>
      xs=6 md=4
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Does 6 parts of the screen mean 6 / N of the screen, and if so what is N?

Comment: @Pixel The Grid is divided into 12 parts. So N = 12.

Comment: thank you - is this true always? Can we not change N somehow?

Comment: it's always 12 - there is a science behind it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and my root component wasn't 100% wide. Setting the width to 100% fixed the issue.

```css
#root {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Width anywhere can be given in single or double quotes, use width part of the style as shown below:

```
    style={{
      width: "80%",
      paddingLeft: 100,
      paddingRight: 200,
      paddingTop: 30,
      paddingBottom: 30,
      border: "3px solid lightGray",
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about this technology... but this should work.

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col md={{ span: 3 }}>Hello</Col>
        <Col md={{ span: 3 }}>Hello2</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  </React.Fragment>
```

EDIT: I might have read wrong your question. Are you referring to screen width? Or "container" div width?

Answer (score 0):

Put an inline style of (padding: '0'). That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3 text-center">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-3 text-center">Hello 2</div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```